# rpart regression tree interpretation

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, rpart

I applied rpart.plot on my regression tree, but I do not know what the values inside the nodes refer to. and how the root is selected?
many thanks.could you please explain what are the values inside of each node? (The picture shows my problem )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEofb.png

Answer (score 5):

According to the `rpart.plot` [vignette](http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf)

For a model with a continuous response (an anova model) each node shows:
- the predicted value.
- the percentage of observations in the node.

Here is an example:

```
data(iris)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

rpart.plot(rpart(Sepal.Width ~., data = iris, cp = 0.1))
```

[image]

The root node displays mean Sepal.Width:

```
with(iris, round(mean(Sepal.Width), 1))
#output
[1] 3.1
```

The left node represents mean Sepal.Width for combined species versicolor and virginica

```
with(iris, round(mean(Sepal.Width[Species != "setosa"]), 1))
#output
[1] 2.9
```

The right node represents mean Sepal.Width for species setosa

```
with(iris, round(mean(Sepal.Width[Species == "setosa"]), 1))
#output
[1] 3.4
```

For a model with a binary response each node shows
- the predicted class.
- the predicted probability
- the percentage of observations in the node.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but in my case, the prediction value in the root is 1 less than the average of target variable. could you please let me know what is the reason? (I didn't round the value. and the result itself is integer )

Comment: @Roze If you could provide the data with `dput` I will take a look. I can not reproduce it with synthetic integer data.

Comment: I wanted to post my data, but there is a limitation of the size of data to post here.how can I post it?

Comment: @Roze. If you can reproduce the issue with a sample of the data (100 rows or so) then post the sample. If not post a download link (github or drpbox) and I will download it and attempt to provide an explanation.

Comment: it was my mistake, you are right, the root node is the average of the dependent variable. my problem was I check the average of whole data while the fitted model was based on the train set of data. Thank you very much.